# How call a method without any parameter?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have a "Getter" method in a Java class :

**Java Code**

```
//Signature : ()Ljava/lang/String;
public String getInputXML() 
{
    return this.inputXML;
}
```

I got the method ID,
I successfully called the constructor of the class and now I want to call the method above.

**C++ Code**

```
std::string JavaInterface::j_getInputXML()
{
    jstring returnString;
    // Call method
    returnString=(jstring) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(javaObj, methodID, NULL);

    // Convert jstring to char*
    const char *js = env->GetStringUTFChars(returnString, NULL);

    // Convert char* to std::string 
    std::string str(js);

    //done
    return str;
}
```

How can I call such method ? Specifically, what should I write when I call the function `CallStaticObjectMethod() ?`

**EDIT :**

```
jstring javaString = NULL;
javaString = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(javaObj, methodID, 0);
```

Comment: First, don't use `CallStaticObjectMethod` for a non-static method.